# Draw bar chart with a complete time series despite missing values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, bar-chart, imputets

I am processing a data set from which I have selected a few lines and columns

```
testfile <- structure(list(date = c("2023-03-30T08:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T09:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-30T10:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T11:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T12:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-30T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T14:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T15:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-30T16:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-30T17:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T06:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-31T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T08:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T09:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-31T10:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T11:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T12:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-31T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T14:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T15:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-03-31T16:00:00.000Z", "2023-03-31T17:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T06:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-01T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T08:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T09:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-01T10:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T11:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T12:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-01T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T14:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T15:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-01T16:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-01T17:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T06:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-02T07:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T08:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T09:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-02T10:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T11:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T12:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-02T13:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T14:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T15:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-02T16:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-02T17:00:00.000Z", "2023-04-03T06:00:00.000Z", 
"2023-04-03T07:00:00.000Z"), pedestrian = c(0, 2.004454343, 22.0155902004, 
26.0200445434, 20.0111358575, 7, 20.0178173719, 15, 51, 41, 25, 
25.008908686, 25.0222717149, 10, 22, 115, 152, 149.0645879733, 
95, 4, 108, 85, 19, 23.5985790409, 31, 42, 35, 24, 18, 34.7234042553, 
27.8252427184, 25, 20, 17, 0, 20.008908686, 28, 38.0670391061, 
42.6666666667, 20.0808080808, 22.0632054176, 28.3636363636, 27.6888361045, 
34, 24.0200445434, 32.3080407701, 10, 14)), row.names = c(NA, 
48L), class = "data.frame")
```

How could I plot a bar chart of `testfile$pedestrian` with a complete time scale as abscissa? Should I start by replacing missing times by NA's? and using `imputeTS` and `ggpplot2`?

### Edit

Is a similar solution working with POSIXct object?

```
testfile <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1680163200, 1680166800, 1680170400, 
1680174000, 1680177600, 1680181200, 1680184800, 1680188400, 1680192000, 
1680195600, 1680242400, 1680246000, 1680249600, 1680253200, 1680256800, 
1680260400, 1680264000, 1680267600, 1680271200, 1680274800, 1680278400, 
1680282000, 1680328800, 1680332400, 1680336000, 1680339600, 1680343200, 
1680346800, 1680350400, 1680354000, 1680357600, 1680361200, 1680364800, 
1680368400, 1680415200, 1680418800, 1680422400, 1680426000, 1680429600, 
1680433200, 1680436800, 1680440400, 1680444000, 1680447600, 1680451200, 
1680454800, 1680501600, 1680505200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Europe/Paris"), pedestrian = c(0, 2.004454343, 22.0155902004, 
26.0200445434, 20.0111358575, 7, 20.0178173719, 15, 51, 41, 25, 
25.008908686, 25.0222717149, 10, 22, 115, 152, 149.0645879733, 
95, 4, 108, 85, 19, 23.5985790409, 31, 42, 35, 24, 18, 34.7234042553, 
27.8252427184, 25, 20, 17, 0, 20.008908686, 28, 38.0670391061, 
42.6666666667, 20.0808080808, 22.0632054176, 28.3636363636, 27.6888361045, 
34, 24.0200445434, 32.3080407701, 10, 14)), row.names = c(NA, 
48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this.

```
with(transform(testfile, date=strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")), 
     plot(date, pedestrian, type='h', lwd=3, lend=2))
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this wonderful solution also works with a slightly different object containing POSIXct dates? I have added an example.

Comment: @leparc Sure, then it's just `with(testfile, plot(date, pedestrian, type='h', lwd=3, lend=2))`. That's what I was actually doing in firsdt line, transforming to POSIX.

Comment: Many thanks, this a very beautiful solution.